# OSMF Player issue in IOS

Tags: osmf

Ive designed a sample osmf player app. Its is working fine in laptop,desktop and android mobiles but in Iphone(IOS OS) the player is embedded, but its not visible. There is no audio as well. Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post if any comments.

Answer (score 0):

there is no flash player on iOS devices.